# Requests/openssl: TypeError: initializer for ctype must be a pointer to same type, not cdata

Tags: openssl, python-requests

I'm having an issue with requests that I couldn't find a solution to elsewhere.

I'm doing a post request to google with some data that contains client id and token info (are just python strings) but I occasionally get this error:

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'int(*)(int, X509_STORE_CTX *)' must be a pointer to same type, not cdata 'int(*)(int, X509_STORE_CTX *)'
```

It seems to work every other time and then it throws this error sometimes. I tried encoding all data/url into 'utf-8' but that didn't seem to help much since I still get the error someimtes. If I turn verify=False it works but I'd like to keep it on. Here is the full trace:

```
url = 'https://accounts.google.com/...'
data = {'refresh_token': ...,
                'client_id': …,
                'client_secret': ...,
                'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
                }

  File "/path/to/file/file.py", line 124, in _my_function.py
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 94, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 362, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 516, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 304, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 722, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 229, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 255, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ctx.set_verify(_openssl_verify[cert_reqs], _verify_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 550, in set_verify
    :param depth: An integer specifying the verify depth
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'int(*)(int, X509_STORE_CTX *)' must be a pointer to same type, not cdata 'int(*)(int, X509_STORE_CTX *)'
```

Using requests 2.4.2 and pyopenssl 0.14. If you have any ideas that would be great, thanks.

Edit: downgrading pyopenssl back to 0.13 makes the error go away.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem, it just started happening. I'm running requests 2.4.3 and pyopenssl 0.14

Comment: I'm seeing this problem when I use the Python requests with mod_wsgi/ apache.

Comment: I get the same thing with mod_wsgi/apache... Did you find a solution?

Comment: Let's continue the chain.. :) @Fredrik did you find a solution?

Comment: This is a bit embarrassing but I did and I have no memory whatsoever about how I solved it :-) I tried too many things at once and was happy to see it go away.